# How to get a SOAP fault message to be WS-I compliance

Tags: soap, soapui

I have this message

> ```
>  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>      <soapenv:Body>
>      <soapenv:Fault>
>         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
>         <faultstring>LOGIN-ERR:Incorrect password - user could not be logged in.</faultstring>
>        </soapenv:Fault>
>      </soapenv:Body>
>    </soapenv:Envelope>
> ```

Schema validated fine, but the SOAP UI tool, when click on "Check WS-I Compliance", it gives a failed status with BP1305 assertion fail.  I can't find what 1305 is and this is the detailed message

> ```
> Result
>   failed
>   Failure Detail Message
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Date: Thu, 22 Jul 2010 20:41:43 GMT
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C9D19FE6AAD89DFCB6BA9FE196E08D40; Path=/
>   Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
> ```

```
  Element Location:
      lineNumber=26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are returning a SOAP Fault message, but with a HTTP status code of 200, SOAP Faults are required to be sent with a HTTP status code of 500.

Comment: You are right, I got it resolved but forgot to post an answer, this is exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the detail element in your fault message. It is a required element if the wsdl fault is produced as a results of the contents of the body element in the request

The message should be like this (detail element should contain application specific info. But it is acceptable to be empty. Not acceptable to be missing):

```
 <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
   <faultstring>LOGIN-ERR:Incorrect password - user could not be logged in.</faultstring>
   <detail></detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

Comment: Nope, still says it's WS-I not compliant.